# How to extract values from a raster given row and colmn?

Tags: r, extract, raster

I have three rasters that I want to extract values corresponding to `x (row)= 5 and y (column) = 7` in each raster so I will get three values.

```
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
 r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r1 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
 r2 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
 r2 <- setValues(r1, 1:ncell(r))
St=stack(r,r1,r2)
```

I tried 
              extract(St, c(5, 7))

but this gave :

```
      extract(St, c(5, 7))
         layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
    [1,]       5       5       5
    [2,]       4      4       4
```

I read my actual files as:

```
    dir1<- list.files("/data/datman", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)

    for (i in 1:697) {
         conne <- file(dir1[i], "rb")
        file<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=500*1000, signed=T)
       file <- raster(t(matrix((data= file), ncol=500, nrow=1000)))}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

If you make a list of the RasterLayer objects you want to subset:

```
rasters=mget(c('r',paste0('r',1:n))) # n = number of rasters
```

(note this will work if you continue to have the r, r1, r2, r3, etc. format that you showed in your question. If you actually have them named in another way then this will have to be modified).

then:

```
sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x,5)[7])
```

Based on your new edit, this code should do everything you need:

```
dir1<- list.files("/data/datman", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)

n <- 697 # number of rasters to combine

rasters <- vector('list', n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  conne <- file(dir1[i], "rb")
  file<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=500*1000, signed=T)
  rasters[[i]] <- raster(t(matrix((data= file), ncol=500, nrow=1000)))}
unlist(rasters)

sapply(rasters, function(x) getValues(x,5)[7])
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I forgot to add the "s" to the end of the new code I added. Corrected now.

Comment: I don't have your data so I cannot reproduce this error, but it seems that you are trying to extract the value in row 418 and column 1191, but the rasters are only 500 columns wide, right? `ncol=500`? This error may be an "out-of-bounds" error.

Comment: If his `sapply` statement works as well then he was first to answer correctly and thus deserves the rep.

Comment: If his `sapply` statement does not work, however, then I have corrected mine to work properly as well (with intellectual contribution from @akrun). This way future readers can choose whichever method they prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
sapply(St@layers, function(x) cellFromRowCol(x,5,7))
```

Or use `unstack`

```
 sapply(unstack(St), function(x) cellFromRowCol(x,5,7))
```

#### Update

Based on the new info, you could try

```
  dir1<- list.files("/data/datman", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
  rasters <- vector('list', 697)
  for (i in 1:697) {
    conne <- file(dir1[i], "rb")
    file<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=500*1000, signed=T)
    rasters[[i]] <- raster(t(matrix((data= file), ncol=500, nrow=1000)))}
 sapply(rasters,function(x) cellFromRowCol(x,5,7))
```

Comment: @sacvf you can concatenate `c` as showed by @CephBirk and the result will be a `list`, from which you can extract using `sapply` or `for` loop.